# The unit ball of $L^{\infty}[0,1]$ is weakly closed in $L^{p}[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

The unit ball of $L^{\infty}[0,1]$ is weakly closed in $L^{p}[0,1]$.

My idea is:

Suppose $A=\{f:||f||_{\infty} \le1\}$, Let $\{f_{\alpha}\}$ be a net in $A$ and $f_{\alpha}\rightarrow f$ weakly.

Since $||f_{\alpha}||_{\infty} \le1$, then $m(\{x:|f_{\alpha}(x)|\ge1\})=0$. Then I have $m(\{x:|f(x)|\ge1\})=0$

Then $\int|f|^{p}=\int_{\{x:|f_{\alpha}(x)|\lt1\}}|f|^{p}\lt \int_{\{x:|f_{\alpha}(x)|\lt1\}}1=m(\{x:|f_{\alpha}(x)|\lt1\})\le m([0,1])=1$.

Thus $f\in L^{p}[0,1]$.

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood the statement. What you have to prove is that the limit lies in the unit ball of $L^{\infty}$. Since the unit ball is a convex set it is weakly closed iff it is norm closed. So what we have to show is the following: $\|f_n\|_{\infty} \leq 1$ for all $n$ and $\int f_n g \to \int fg$ for all $g \in L^{q}$ implies $\|f\|_{\infty} \leq 1$ (where $q$ is the index conjugate to $p$). To prove this just note that $\int_A f_n \to \int _A f$ for every Borel set $A$. Since $\|f_n\|_{\infty} \leq 1$ it follows that $|\frac 1 {m(A)} \int_A f| \leq 1$ for every Borel set $A$ of positive measure. This implies that $|f| \leq 1$ almost everywhere which means $f$ belongs to the closed unit ball.